# Water valve for LG washer with 5 solenoids. Old part solenoids connect on top vs new part connection on bottom of solenoid

Tags: electrical

Lg water valve for washer includes 5 solenoids. The original part the connections for the solenoids were on top and the plastic connection with the wires appears to have an arrow on top of the plastic. The new part every the same Except the solenoid connections on the bottom of them. Do I plug the plastic connections the same way with the arrow facing up or do I need to rotate the plastic connection 180 degrees.

Comment: a picture would help us

Comment: Not only a picture of the new & old parts, but a specific model number would be most helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Most solenoids work the same regardless of the polarity.
I would say if the connections fit, go with that.

Answer (score 0):

If the solenoids mount is the kind where you can pull them off and rotate then do that.

Otherwise the solenoids do not care about electrical polarity.